# query/script/stored procedure which will return a single table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query. can someone help rapping this in a cursor.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.[dbo].[#Results]') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[#Results] 
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Results] ( 
[DatabaseName]     VARCHAR(128)                         NULL,
[DatabaseVersion]  VARCHAR(128)                         NULL,
[DateChangedOn]    DATETIME                             NULL)

EXEC sp_msForEachDb '
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].sys.objects WHERE NAME = ''stdVersions'')
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #Results 
    SELECT 
      ''?'' AS [DatabaseName],
      v.[DatabaseVersion],
      l.[DateChangedOn]
      FROM [?].dbo.stdVersions v 
      CROSS JOIN [?].dbo.stdChangeLog l
END'

SELECT * FROM #Results ORDER BY DateChangedOn
```

the query should return list of all database names in the server and within the databases return the databaseversion column and DateChangeOn Column. All the databases in the server contain tables named stdVersions and stdChangeLog of which the stdVersion table have a single row of DatabaseVersion comes and stdChangeLog table have a single row of DateChangedOn.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of creating a cursor on the #Results table.

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname
  , @DatabaseVersion sysname
  , @DateChangedOn datetime;   

DECLARE DatabaseList CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
    SELECT  DatabaseName
          , DatabaseVersion
          , DateChangedOn
    FROM    #Results
    ORDER BY DateChangedOn;

OPEN DatabaseList;
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN

    FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseList INTO
          @DatabaseName
        , @DatabaseVersion
        , @DateChangedOn;

    IF @@FETCH_STATUS = -1 BREAK;

    --process row here

END;

CLOSE DatabaseList;

DEALLOCATE DatabaseList;
```

You mention that the "std" tables exist in all databases.  If these tables does not include system databases, change the IF statement in the script below to exclude those:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].sys.objects WHERE NAME = ''stdVersions'')
    AND [?] NOT IN(N'master', N'model', N'tempdb', N'msdb', N'SSISDB')
```